# Reading Multiple XML Files and Order Listview

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, multiple-columns, openfiledialog

Hi good afternoon my question is:

Im writing a code to:

1. Read Multiple files: Ican read only one file with the openfiledialog if i select more than one the program only takes one, i think i can use a foreach but i dont know how to implement.
2. Order the xml nodes into a list view, i have a list view and the output has to be like this:

---

```
Test Name     Limit Judgment    Measurement    High Limit     Low Limit
Main__checkt      0                 3               5            3
Main__Initia      0                 4               4            3 
Main__Serial      0                 3               4            3
```

But my output is this:

---

```
Test Name     Limit Judgment    Measurement    High Limit     Low Limit
Main__Initia      0                 3               5            3
Main__Serial      0                 3               5            3 
Main__Cylind      0                 3               5            3
```

The programa takes the first row and iterate in the different columns how i can order this?

This is a sample of my XML File:

[XML FILE](http://justpaste.it/gz66)

This is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "XML | *.xml";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    ofd.ShowDialog();
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(ofd.FileName); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"
    ListViewItem lvi;

    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/LogBatch/LogTestplan/LogTest");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {

        string tnam = xn["TestName"].InnerText;

        lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = tnam;
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

        XmlNodeList xnList2 = xml.SelectNodes("/LogBatch/LogTestplan/LogTest/LogLimit");
        foreach (XmlNode xn2 in xnList2)
        {

            string limjud = xn2["LimitJudgment"].InnerText;
            string limlm = xn2["LimitLastMeasuredValue"].InnerText;
            string limhl = xn2["LimitHighLimit"].InnerText;
            string limlw = xn2["LimitLowLimit"].InnerText;

            lvi.SubItems.Add(limjud);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(limlm);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(limhl);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(limlw);
            string nomval = "4";
            lvi.SubItems.Add(nomval);
            string devstd = "0.46291";
            lvi.SubItems.Add(devstd);
            string cp = "0.72";
            lvi.SubItems.Add(cp);
        }
    }
}
```

Help please.
Thank you.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect for complete code since your question is too broad for that<sup>1</sup>. But here are the main points to accomplish both requirements :

1. When using `Multiselect` mode, you should check [`FileDialog.FileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of singular `FileName` property. At this point you must be able to easily iterate through `FileNames` and load each of them into `XmlDocument` object.
2. To get `<LogLimit>` node that correspond to current `<LogTest>` in your outer `foreach` loop you should use XPath relative to current `<LogLimit>`.

So instead of using full path :

```
XmlNodeList xnList2 = xml.SelectNodes("/LogBatch/LogTestplan/LogTest/LogLimit");
```

try relative path :

```
XmlNodeList xnList2 = xn.SelectNodes("./LogLimit");
```

or simply :

```
XmlNodeList xnList2 = xn.SelectNodes("LogLimit");
```

You may want to consider `SelectSingleNode()` to replace `SelectNodes()` in context where you know exactly that there won't be more than one node satisfies the XPath.

1) <sub>Post separate questions for each particular problem. And instead of throwing all your codes and full XML file content, try to [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The example will help a lot in clarifying the problem, especially when We have limitation in writing English (I almost never write/speak English other than in this site too :p). You may learn something or even find a solution yourself in the process of creating the example</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and i will follow your recommendations :) im new writing in forums, i learn a lot of things here.